# What is the Optimal Parameter Distribution for tuning Hyperparameters using random search

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest, supervised-learning, hyperparameters

The machine learning algorithms from SK-learn take a huge amount of parameters, and I am having a real hard time finding out which interval I should assign for the Random Search tuning algorithm. I am currently using 7 different ML algorithms (SVM, LDA, LR, DT, GBC, KNN), but let us take Random Forest as an example.

```
X, y = df.something().....
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    param_dist = {"criterion": ["gini", "entropy"],
                   "max_features": ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
                   "max_depth": randint(1, 100),
                   "min_samples_split": randint(2, 150),
                   "min_samples_leaf": randint(1, 150),
                   "max_leaf_nodes": randint(2, 100),
                   "n_estimators": randint(2, 200)}
    model = RandomForestClassifier()
    ts_rs = run_randomsearch(X, y, model, param_dist, cv=5, n_iter_search=100)
```

**Overall**: How do I assign the best parameter distribution to search within?
**More specifically**: How do I find out whether its better to search for the max-depth in [1:10000], rather than, lets say; [1:10]? Can anybody recommend any optimum? (maybe even with a source) Currently, this is the closest i get: [How to tune parameters in Random Forest, using Scikit Learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107820/how-to-tune-parameters-in-random-forest-using-scikit-learn)

Comment: Recommending external tutorials is explicitly outside the scope of StackOverflow. Instead, describe the problem and what *specifically* has been done to solve it. You may benefit from [ask].

Comment: Just changed it slightly. I think the problem is pretty clear: How do I define the "best" parameter distributions to search within?

Comment: IMHO, you need to _understand_, what each parameter means and at least approximately understand the math behind the algorithm. For example, for the most problems max_depth 100 make _no_ sense. Ask yourself why and try to answer this question. This will be your first step to understanding.